# Can't launch eclipse from the command line in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I tried to open eclipse via this command: `eclipse &` but I get this result in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform
```

I don't have any problems launching eclipse via the desktop icon.

In addition when I try this command to figure out the variable of path:

```
echo $ECLIPSE_HOME
```

I get this:

```
/opt/ALL_myprograms/eclipse/eclipse
```

Comment: Is your title misspelled ?

Comment: This question seems more fits for [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) than here.

Comment: What happens when you start using these commands `opt/ALL_myprograms/eclipse/eclipse` from terminal ?

Comment: @Saurabh
sorry,
I fix it now

Comment: @Gk.
it works with this: **/opt/ALL_myprograms/eclipse/eclipse&** but why just eclipse& doesn't work ???

Comment: @Yen Ines Okies,, What response you are getting  ? Are you trying `eclipse &` in eclipse folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ECLIPSE_HOME` is not needed here, you either need to set `$PATH` to include the path to your eclipse executable or you can start eclipse from the terminal giving the full path to the executable, e.g. `/opt/ALL_myprograms/eclipse/eclipse`

Comment: it works with this :
**/opt/ALL_myprograms/eclipse/eclipse&** 

but why just eclipse& doesn't work ???

Comment: Because /opt/ALL_myprograms/eclipse is not part of your $PATH: Just do a `echo $PATH` and you'll see what I mean

Comment: this is what I get with 

echo $PATH
`/opt/ALL_myprograms/eclipse/eclipse:/opt/ALL_myprograms/jdk1.6.0_35/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
[1]+  Fini                    /opt/ALL_myprograms/eclipse/eclipse`

weird but it's defined there in the path

Comment: No, it is not in your $PATH! $PATH must include the directory where the executable(s) is/are  located, not the path to the executable itself.

Comment: it works now,I just edit the bashrc,I removed the last eclipse one.
thanks a lot
you made my day
thx :))))